# Manipulating the appearance of instrument names and staff group names

Tags: lilypond

In Lilypond, I am trying to change the appearance of instrument names and staff group names. Below are two images; the first is what I currently have and the second is the look I am trying to achieve.

[image: My current output]

In my current output, the instrument names are all aligned with the staff group name (which is rotated).

[image: The desired look]

In the image of the look I want, the instrument names are "under" (to the right) of the staff group name and the staff group brace.

I have been unable to find where to change the look of these. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To get a simple square bracket you need to use:
`\set StaffGroup.systemStartDelimiter = #'SystemStartSquare`

But to get it the instrument names "under" you'll need to apply and extra-offset:
`\override StaffGroup.SystemStartSquare.extra-offset = #'(-18 . 0)`

To get vertical text you can use:
`\rotate #90`

There are some other tricks in the code below, and I'm sure you'll need to make some adjustments, but I hope you'll be able to manage from here.

### Code

Something like this:

```
\version "2.21.0"

flute = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = "Flute"
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "flute"
        \clef "treble"
        \key aes \major
        \transposition c'
            aes''2. |
    }
}

altoSaxophone = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = \markup {\concat{E\super\flat} Alto}
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "alto sax"
        \clef "treble"
        \key f \major
        \transposition ees
            d'8 r8 r4 r4 |
    }
}

tenorSaxophone = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = \markup {\concat{B\super\flat} Ten.}
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "tenor sax"
        \clef "treble"
        \key bes \major
        \transposition bes,
            d''4 r4 r4 |
    }
}

baritoneSaxophone = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName = \markup {\concat{E\super\flat} Bar.}
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "baritone sax"
        \clef "treble"
        \key f \major
        \transposition es,
            a'2 r4 |
    }
}

bassSaxophoneContrabassClarinet = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.instrumentName =
            \markup {
                \center-column {
                    \line {\concat{B\super\flat} Bass /}
                    \line {C. Bs. Cl}
                }
            }
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "clarinet"

        \clef "treble"
        \key bes \major
        \transposition bes,,
            d'4 r4 r4 |
    }
}

contents = {
    \time 3/4
    
    \new StaffGroup {
        <<
            \flute
            
            \new StaffGroup {
                \set StaffGroup.systemStartDelimiter = #'SystemStartSquare
                \override StaffGroup.SystemStartSquare.extra-offset = #'(-18 . 0)
                \set StaffGroup.instrumentName = \markup {\hspace #-12 \rotate #90 Sax.}
                <<
                    \altoSaxophone
                    \tenorSaxophone
                    \baritoneSaxophone
                    \bassSaxophoneContrabassClarinet
                >>
            }
        >>
    }
}

\score {
    \contents
    \layout {
        indent = 35
    }
}

\score {
    \contents
    \midi { }
}
```

[image: image of LilyPond output PDF]